# SwiftUI NavigationBarTitle glitch with PageTabViewStyle() (not smooth)

Tags: swiftui

I want to use a TabView with PageTabViewStyle in a NavigationView. Unfortunately, the NavigationView / NavigationBar has a weird transition glitch when jumping from inline to large.
This is the code:

```
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                Text("Animation glitch")
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Animation glitch")
        }
```

[image: This is the glitch]

Comment: Looks ok to me...

Comment: It's hard to show it in a gif. I compared it to a normal list, which feels much smoother. Try it yourself!

Comment: I did! And it was pretty much the same as all navigation bar animations. They are rarely completely smooth.

Comment: Try it on a real device, it might just be difficult and not optimized for an intel gpu. Unless you have the M1

Comment: `navigationBarTitle` is being deprecated use `navigationTitle`